# Using nouns with different prepositions

Tags: prepositions

Is the following sentence correct:

"I thank you for sharing with me your knowledge **of** and passion **for** X"?

If not, how should the sentence be phrased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two prepositions and the syntactical construction they're involved in are all fine, although the elaborate construction is rather bureaucratic.

Note, however, that we thank a benefactor (*you*) **for** the benefit (*sharing...*).

Comment: So, the answer to the question is: the sentence is incorrect. It should start with "I thank you *for* sharing with me".

Comment: The omission of *for* was a typo. Too bureaucratic, i agree! Will find another way to phrase things!